# queryselectorall selects also child classes

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors, selectors-api

Example -

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="main child"></div>
```

On chrome devtools `document.querySelectorAll(".main")` selects main & main child.

How can I select only main?

Comment: Don't put the class `main` on the second element if you don't want it to be selected?

Comment: Please post the complete code - what selector are you using with `querySelectorAll`? We can't help you fix it if you don't tell us.

Comment: I'm scraping from a website I don't control that. @Bergi

Comment: what query are you using?

Comment: It's not a child, it's a sibling, fwiw. A child would be _inside_ the first `div`.

Comment: We only know what you tell us in the question. [Edit] your question to include all constraints you are under, and a [mre] (preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)).

Comment: A better solution would be to use `document.querySelectorAll('[class="main"]')` if you actually want elements that have the one and only class "main".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.main:not(.child)` to select only those elements that have the `main` class but not the `child` class.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.main:not(.child)'))
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="main child"></div>
```

[Read more about `:not()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: Yes it is -- added a demo.

Comment: This (and the duplicate) answers the question in the most literal reading of the question, but not the actual question asked: "How can I select only main?" If there are hundreds of elements, each with main and one or more other unique classes, the selector would soon grow unmanageable.